# Android : getting comments on checkin place using foursquare api

Tags: android, comments, foursquare, checkin

I can retrive my checkin place using   https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/USER_ID/checkins/?oauth_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&v=20121109.

This api return everything about my checkin place on json fromat except the comments under checkin place.Results only show total number of comments but not comments.

But i need comments.Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the checkin id to retrieve the full details for the checkins with comments:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/CHECKIN_ID?oauth_token=OAUTH_TOKEN&v=20121109

API-Endpoint: [https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/CHECKIN_ID](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/checkins/checkins)

The response includes the comments:

```
 comments: {
  count: 1
  items: [
  {
   id: "..."
   createdAt: ...
   user: {
    id: "..."
    firstName: "..."
    lastName: "..."
    relationship: "self"
    photo: {
     prefix: "https://irs2.4sqi.net/img/user/"
     suffix: "..."
    }
   }
   text: "Hello that is a comment"
  }
  ]
 }
```